# Java String Split by \\s+ and by String Array

Tags: java, string, split

In this code a user will input some text. It then needs to be split by whitespace - I am currently using:

`for (String inputSplit : userInput.split("[\\s+]")) {
    // stuff happens here
}`

It now needs to **also** be split by **any** operator which is stored in a variable called `ops`.

`private String[] ops = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "^"};`

I'd like to keep it referencing ops, otherwise if I change something there, I have to remember to change it in this string split part too.

How can I just add this to the expression so that it reads 'split by whitespace or any one of these ops'?

e.g. `userInput.split("[\\s+]|[ops]")`

Extra info:

- I am new to Java
- JDK Amazon Corretto 11
- IntelliJ IDEA CE 2019.3.2

Comment: Also I need it to split on new line, so I have changed the split to `userInput.split("\\n+|\\s+")` but I still can't get the ops array to work.

Answer (score 0):

store the separator in string with or condition and pass it

```
String ops = "\\s+|\+|\-|\*|\/|\%|\^"
userInput.split(ops)
```

Comment: I get an error of: "Illegal escape character in string literal"

Comment: can you remove + after s and try String ops = "\\s|\+|\-|\*|\/|\%|\^"

Answer (score 0):

You could build a `String` by joining the array and then pass it to your regular expression (`+|-|*|/|%|^`), the only problem is that you are using some characters that have special meaning in regular expression (like `*` - Kleene star) and these should be escaped, whereas others should not.

To keep control ofm this, you can map each character you want to split the string by to the regular (part of) expression that should be used:

```
public static final Map<Character, String> opsToRegularExpression = Map.of(
        '+', "\\+",
        '-', "-",
        '*', "\\*",
        '/', "/",
        '%', "%",
        '^', "\\^"
);

public static final String regexpString =
        String.format("\\n+|\\s+|%s", String.join("|", opsToRegularExpression.values()));

// ...

for (String inputSplit : userInput.split(regexpString)) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can construct regular expression, then use it in order to separate how you want.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ops = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "^"};
        String separators = "\\s";

        String userInput = "QWE QWSDF DSFDG DFG GSFH GDSG DSFG DSF+6561 AS/DAS 654654 132-6564 ASD*ASD DFGD^FGF";

        for (String separator : ops) {
            separators += "\\" + separator;
        }

        for (String inputSplit : userInput.split("[" + separators + "]")) {
            System.out.println(inputSplit);
        }
    }
}
```